# PHP creating folder with two variables gives wrong foldername

Tags: php, file-upload, mkdir

I'm trying to create a random foldername for upload of files.
The folderpath shall be like "**receivedfiles/$name$date/**". Instead i get this: "**receivedfiles/ . 13.06.2016/**". I really don't know what is wrong...

The variable $name is user input and can be e.g. "Simon" or "Simon Jensen" depending on what the user wants.

```
$d = date('d.m.y');
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/. $name . $d ./";
mkdir($varfoldername , 0777 , true);
$upload_folder = $varfoldername;
```

Thanks to great help i have removed the dots from code above, please see code below which only name the folder with the date.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$d = date('d.m.y');
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/$name$d/";
mkdir($varfoldername , 0777 , true);
$upload_folder = $varfoldername;
```

**Solution:** $name was first specified later in script. Moving that atop solved part of the problem. Changed folder path as above solved the rest - thank you all :)

Comment: the problem is in the $_POST['name']

Comment: I use this for sending an email with the path among other infos. That part works.

Comment: ok but try to make a print of $name before the $d variable to see what is $name content

Comment: Hi CiroRa
I just found the problem. The problem was that this is code from my send email fom. The email is composed below and fileupload is above. So ofcourse the variable wasn't know at that line. Please update your answer with this so i can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. The problem was that this is code from send email form. The email is composed below and fileupload is above. So of course the variable wasn't know at that line.

Extraordinarily, you've written the solution in the question

```
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/$name$date/";
```

since it's double-quoted php interprets $.. as variable and print its content

by the way, print $varfoldername to see what is the output

Comment: Thx. I updated the code above and added an extra line. I only get the date as a foldername.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the extra dots are there because you are not concatenating correctly. The 2nd line should be something like

```
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/" . $name . $d . "/";
```

or you could remove the dots inside your string since you are using double quotes for your folder name value.

Comment: Thx. I updated the code above and added an extra line. I only get the date as a foldername.

Comment: If you get nothing back for $name, then $_POST['name'] does not exist

Comment: I use it to send an email and the name comes through via email, so i believe it is there. But if there variabel is used once, is it then emptied or does it depends on what line it is written?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check whether the `$name` variable is not empty.

Then, use [`sprintf`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for creating the path. It provides more flexible formatting and helps you to get rid of redundant spaces/dots/etc. Try this:

```
$varfoldername = sprintf('../receivedfiles/%s%s/', $name, $d);
```